# How to output multiple group by output in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I need to do multiple count and do a group by , I am trying this in hive but its error out, any body good with hiveQL can help here , how to do same in either hive/pig

Logic for 1st count

`Select col1,clo2 ,col3 , count (distinct col4, col5) from table1  where col6 = 1 group by col1,clo2 ,col3`

Logic for 2nd count

`Select col1,clo2 ,col3 , count (distinct col4, col5) from table1  where col7 = 1 group by col1,clo2 ,col3`

Final OP expected as below  :

```
col1,clo2 ,col3 ,count1 ,count2
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

@Navneet, Why would you like to find out `count (distinct col4, col5)`? As this will always give you output `1`. So your `count1 and count2 will be always 1`.

Comment: 'table1' is a join table and it has multiple records with key as col4, col5 . there are different columns in 'table1' which can have value 1 or 0, the count gives how many such distinct value we have when col6 = 1 or col7 = 1

Comment: Could you please share the result of both of select queries mentioned above for your dB. So that we can come to some conclusion.